# iPhone message preview panel

Tags: html, css

So, at my jobb im currently tasked with creating a preview panel for a ios message.
It needs to be "as exact as possible" so i was thinking using css pixel = device pixels / device pixel ratio for width and height. Would that be a good way to go? What would the scale for the fonts be if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend going that direction. Every iPhone is of a different size. And some users might enlarge the text on their iPhones so that they can read it better. I would make it as responsive as possible.

This is a tool that I use when developing for different screen sizes: http://www.responsinator.com/

If you want to copy and paste your code here I can help you accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for your input. No code has been written yet as i was doing some looking around how to solve it. Your suggestion on going maximum effort on responsiveness is probably how it's going to be done.